# run my code , every time i change my $(window).width()

Tags: javascript

I need that every time I resize the $(window).width() [ for example resize my Firefox ] with mouse . my function is run

for example

```
var width = $(window).width() ;

if ( width < 1000 ) { alert('1') }
if ( width > 1000 ) { alert('0') }
```

and this dynamically run every time i change the $(window).width() with my mouse

Comment: whats the type of $(window)? please post an sscce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
//  do your stuff here
});
```